# How to disable/enable authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.0 based on settings?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

We've got an API in ASP.NET Core 2.0, secured with 2 different type JwtTokens. Our controllers have the `[Authorize]` attribute, and specifying the `AuthorizationSchemes`

That's all working fine, except that I want to disable this based on appsettings.

I have spent hours, but no solution yet. I've had a look at policies, requirements, etc. but all of them expect a token; thus the policy / requirement won't be evaluated if the token is not present.

I've also looked at a custom `Authorize` attribute, but that's advised against.

Comment: I wonder why would you do such a thing? And a custom Authorize attribute is excactly what I would do. Check the setting and if it pans out continue the authentication process or not.

Comment: We only want to disable this on our development environments. Reason is, that currently our client when run locally is not able to add these authorization headers. Plus, we want to easily be able to use PostMan to test our API in DEV.

Comment: Just so I understand it correctly: You have authentication with JWT set up and just want to be able to disable authentication completely, so all routes that require authorized users will just let you through without authentication?

Comment: @poke yes that's exactly what I want. To make it more complicated, different controllers use different JWT tokens. So, a filter configured in Startup doesn't work as that applies to all requests. Maybe we have to go to one JWT token?

Comment: Do you want to only disable *one* token though? Or disable it all? Is simply getting a proper authentication provider for your dev environment not an option?

Answer (score 0):

There is your `launchSettings.json` which will look like this:

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": true,
        "anonymousAuthentication": false,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52171/",
            "sslPort": 0
        }
    } // additional options trimmed
}
```

just disable the options you want.

for more info see this [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x) for windows authentication

for identity and authorization see this [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

According to your insight, I will update my answer with this [article](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/). It provides info on how to store the credentials on `appsettings.json`and therefore, once you have them in `appsettings.json` you can easily disable them.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how that relates though; I'm not using identities or windows auth. I'm using JwtTokens with custom key/secret, shared by client and API. I just want to disable the JwtToken validation based on some logic.
Hope I didn't misunderstand you.